# Calculate payment sum after pulling dynamic date range from different table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to calculate the sum of payments using two different tables. For every ID, I need to consecutively pick up dates from first table and calculate the sum of the amt from the second table.

**Update-** I have ~200 Ids and require the below logic for every id. I was thinking of using dynamic SQL, self join on DateTable and two flags on Rank to pick up Date(S) from Date table.

Example -

```
SELECT ID, SUM(AMT) FROM PAYMENT P INNER JOIN DateTable D ON P.ID = D.ID 
WHERE PAYDATE BETWEEN '6/1/2019' AND '2/1/2020'
```

then it should do the same sum for next two dates 5/1/2019 AND 6/1/2020-

```
SELECT ID, SUM(AMT) FROM PAYMENT P INNER JOIN DateTable D ON P.ID = D.ID 
WHERE PAYDATE BETWEEN '5/1/2019' AND '6/1/2020'
```

First table - DateTable:

[image]

Second table - Payment:

[image]

```
> Expected Output: 
   ID     Sum 
   111    37    (10+13+14) 
   111    219   (65+45+47+62)
   222    165   (89+76)
   and so on...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `lag()` and `join`:

```
select i.id, d.date, sum(p.amt)
from (select d.*,
             lag(date) over (partition by id order by date) as prev_date
      from datetable d
     ) d cross join
     (select distinct id from payment
     ) i left join
     payment p
     on p.id = i.id and
        p.paydate > d.prev_date and
        p.paydate <= date and
group by i.id, d.date;
```

Comment: I should have mentioned it before. i have ~ 200 Ids on which I have to run the same logic. Above will inly run on id 111. I was trying to create a dynamic sql but hitting a wall on that.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, @JatinGarg, even if you did want this to run only on id 111, you'd still need to filter or partition the subquery. To make it run on all ids, use `parition by d.id` with the lag() function and replace `p.id = 111` with `p.id = d.id`

Comment: @JatinGarg . . . I updated the answer for that case.  The query generates all combinations of dates and `id`s and then joins to the payments.

Comment: @GordonLinoff , @JatinGarg but why the new subquery? It cross joins every possible id with every possible interval start date, that doesn't make sense to me. The initial subquery already gives you the start date and end date for each interval and the (person, I suppose) id it corresponds to. I still think the condition should be `p.id = d.id`

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Thanks Gordon. It works great. We don;t need a cross join. It works fine without that

Answer (score 0):

you can use `UNION ALL` to combine the result of these 2 query

```
SELECT ID, SUM(AMT) FROM PAYMENT P INNER JOIN DateTable D ON P.ID = D.ID 
WHERE PAYDATE BETWEEN '6/1/2019' AND '2/1/2020'
GROUP BY ID

UNION ALL

SELECT ID, SUM(AMT) FROM PAYMENT P INNER JOIN DateTable D ON P.ID = D.ID 
WHERE PAYDATE BETWEEN '5/1/2019' AND '6/1/2020'
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: Squirrel - I need to do this dynamically for ~200 Ids.